# jquery obj.find(' > a.link').live()?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to setup some click events inside a jquery plugin.

The plugin is acting on the tfoot of a table.
the instance of this tfoot is stored in a variable 'foot';

I am trying to use this;

```
foot.find(' > div#table_pageination > #pages > a.link').live('click', function(){
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

However this simply has no effect.

(doing console.log(foot.find(' > div#table_pageination > #pages > a.link')); returns the links I am trying to setup.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.live()` cannot be used with chaining. You can use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `live` functions on non-absolute queries. That is, when start with a base set of elements, (`foot` in this case).

Since you have two elements with an `id` in there, you have some level of redundancy which could be removed. Change it to: `$('#pages > a.link').live(...)`

Comment: but,

there may be several tables on the page that have the #pages div, hence refering to foot, any other ideas?

Comment: @Hailwood - hate to use this phrase, but you're doing it wrong. IDs *must* be unique per document. You should be using classes instead. Perhaps try this: `$('tfoot > div.table_pagination > .pages > a.link').live(...)`